# Implementing Undo/Redo methods using Stacks

Tags: java, stack, undo-redo

I want to create "undo" and "redo" buttons using stacks (not swing).

When "undo" is clicked, Textfields, Lists and everything need to be undone/redone. I know I have to use pop, push, etc. But what do I put in the stacks? Textfield values? List contents?

Example:

- I register a student in a school.

  - Student infos in textfields are changed
  - The list of students contains the new student

How do I reset these?

And is there a way to just stock the current state of the project's data in the stack?

Comment: You might need to clarify a little. What exactly do you need to undo? The student registration, or what people write in the textfields? Where do you store the registered student?

Comment: i need to undo every thing. the student objects are stored in a list. the list and the textfields need to be undone, just like a ctr+z, if there was something else before , it needs to show up  instead of a blank txt field

Comment: I updated you text and reduced it to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, I got you right, since I do not really understand what you mean by "using stacks (not swing)". A `Stack` is a data structure and *Swing* is a UI framework. So those have basically nothing to do with each other.

Implementing undo/redo is typically done by using one of the following approaches. Which one you should use depends on your desired undo/redo behavior.

> Undo/redo using the *Command Pattern*.

Implementing this approach would look something like this:

```
public interface ICommand {
    void do();
    void undo();
}

public class StudentSaveCommand implements ICommand {

    public StudentSaveCommand(Student student) { ... }
    [...]
}
```

In the `do()` implementation of the `StudentSaveCommand` class you implement the action which should be taken to actually save the given student, e.g. inserting the data into the database, saving to a file or simply adding it to a list.
In the `undo()` implementation you implement the action to revert the `do()` implementation, e.g. deleting from the database, deleting the file or removing it from the list.

To finally implement the undo/redo feature using `Stack`s you would do something like this:

```
public void btnSaveStudentClickHandler() {
    ICommand c = new IStudentSaveCommand(theStudentFromGUI);
    c.do();
    _redoStack.clear();
    _undoStack.push(c);
}

public void btnUndoClickHandler() {
    ICommand undoCommand = _undoStack.pop();
    undoCommand.undo();
    _redoStack.push(undoCommand); 
}

public void btnRedoClickHandler() {
    ICommand redoCommand = _redoStack.pop();
    redoCommand.do();
    _undoStack.push(redoCommand);
}
```

To easily reflect the changes on your model to your GUI I would implement/use some sort of data binding. As you can see, this approach is not that appropriate to implement undo/redo on a very fine-grained level, e.g. changing a student's name in a textbox. Here comes the second approach into play.

> Undo/redo using *[Memento Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)*.

Using this pattern allows you to save and restore states of an object, e.g. a `Student`. The implementation for an undo/redo feature using this pattern and `Stack`s the code would probably look something like this:

```
public void txtStudentNameLostFocusHandler() {
    Memento sm = student.getSavedState();
    _redoStack.clear();
    _undoStack.push(sm);
}

public void btnUndoClickHandler() {
    Memento m = _undoStack.pop();
    student.restoreSavedState(m);
    _redoStack.push(m);
}

// [...] Redo implementation straight-forward
```

To reflect the changes which were made to the `Student` object I also would prefer data binding or implement a method like the following which must be called after an undo/redo action:

```
public void updateStudentGUI(Student student) {
    txtName.setText(student.getName());
    [...]
}
```

---

To have the advantages of both approaches in your undo/redo implementation you also can combine those. However, the best approach depends strongly on the specification, respectively what you really want to achieve.